# AWS step function data conversion

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have the following output, from a call to a lambda.

```json
  "result": {
    "ids": [
      "1",
      "17",
      "100"
    ]
  }
```

How does one convert an array, and expand it into an Input that will be consumed by a subsequent process? I'd like the input to look something like MapInput. Its worth mentioning I have $time and $id passed to the step function.

```json
  "MapInput": [
    {
      "tenant_id": "1",
      "run_id.$": "$.id",
      "run_timestamp.$": "$.time",
    },
    {
      "tenant_id": "17",
      "run_id.$": "$.id",
      "run_timestamp.$": "$.time",
    },
    {
      "tenant_id": "100",
      "run_id.$": "$.id",
      "run_timestamp.$": "$.time",
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) over the tenant ids. The `Parameters` attribute reshapes the input using the [Context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html#contextobject-map).

```json
{
  "StartAt": "MyMap",
  "States": {
    "MyMap": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.result.ids",
      "ResultPath": "$.mapResult",
      "Parameters": {
        "tenant_id.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value",
        "run_id.$": "$$.Execution.Input.id",
        "run_timestamp.$": "$$.Execution.Input.timestamp"
      },
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "No-Op",
        "States": {
          "No-Op": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

output:

```json
{
  "id": "a",
  "timestamp": 1666115702715,
  "result": {
    "ids": ["1", "17", "100"]
  },
  "mapResult": [
    {
      "tenant_id": "1",
      "run_id": "a",
      "run_timestamp": 1666115702715
    },
    {
      "tenant_id": "17",
      "run_id": "a",
      "run_timestamp": 1666115702715
    },
    {
      "tenant_id": "100",
      "run_id": "a",
      "run_timestamp": 1666115702715
    }
  ]
}
```